# Best technology or algorithm to find best matches on a large database

Tags: database, algorithm, search, find

We plan to have a large database with objects that have structure like this:

Person1:
  skills: ['a','b','c']

Person2:
  skills: ['a','b']

Person3:
  skills: ['d','e','f']

Person4:
  skills: ['a','b','d']

And then given an input of skills, the algorithm/technology shoud be able to quickly find the best fit Person given some skills.

Example:
Find person with skills: a, b -> returns the list ordened like this [Person1,Person2,Person4,Person3]

So i would like some recommendations on what technology (database / language) to build this on top and which algorithm should perform good on a database with about 10k registers.

Comment: Any relational database should be able to do this.  Do you have something in mind?

Comment: No, right now we have only the dataset. We want to select the best database to solve this kind of search

Comment: Can you give an idea on what would look like the query on a sql  db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [**inverted index**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) for this problem. The basic idea is to invert your representation from

```
1 -> a, b, c
2 -> a, b
3 -> d, e, f
4 -> a, b, d
```

to

```
a -> 1, 2, 4
b -> 1, 2, 4
c -> 1
d -> 3, 4
e -> 3
f -> 3
```

Now for each skill, you have a list of people capable of that skill (possibly ordered by skill level). In order to get the result for skills a, b you scan through the lists of a and b and increase the counter of each person you found, which gives you persons 1, 2, 4 each with count 3.

This is basically the same index structure as used for text search (here you have documents containing terms). Systems like [elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) include more advanced inverted indices that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of the database you're planning to use queries you consider primary (the ones used more often) may have a huge benefit from indexing.

You should create the index in the same order of the queries. Based on the model you used for your example I take it that you're using a NoSQL DB. Indexes provide better performance on search but takes more time to record.

Finally I have to say that 10k is not a big collection, but querying nested arrays may be much slower without index.